# Inserting checkbox, radio and dropdown values from VBA form into Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit of a multi-faceted question regarding inserting checkbox, radio and dropdown values from a VBA form into the Excel spreadsheet. I am trying to accommodate a couple case scenarios in my code at the moment.

The first set of items I want to insert is a **checkbox** with the following names/values:

```
Name         Value
==========   =====
chk_week1    1
chk_week2    2
chk_week3    3
chk_week4    4
chk_week5    5
chk_week6    6
chk_week7    7
chk_week8    8
chk_week9    9
chk_week10   10
chk_week11   11
chk_week12   12
chk_week13   13
chk_week14   14
chk_week15   15
```

If the user makes a selection of several checkboxes then it should be inserted in the form `1,2,4,5` - for example if the user selects `chk_week1, chk_week2, chk_week4 and chk_week5`.

---

The second set of items I want to insert is a single pick from radio group with the followng names/values within the frame `fr_Priority`:

```
Name         Value
==========   =====
priority_y   Yes
priority_n   No
```

So if the user selects `priority_y` then `Yes` is inserted into the Excel spreadsheet.

---

The third set of items I want to insert comes from three drop downs. This is fairly straightforward, but the user is required to make a selection in all three drop downs. If they are not interested in a preference then they select `'No Preference'`. If the user makes this decision then nothing should be inserted into cell. The following names/values are present:

```
Name         
==========   
cbo_fac1   
cbo_fac2
cbo_fac3
```

For instance if the user makes a selection of `111,222,No Preference` in **cbo_fac1**, **cbo_fac2**, **cbo_fac3** then only `111,222` gets inserted. If `111,No Preference,No Preference` is selected then only `111` gets inserted.

---

This is the code I am using right now:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("main")

' Copy the data to the database
' Get last empty cell in column A
Set rng1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)

deptCodeSplit = Split(cbo_deptCode.Value, " ")

rng1.Offset(1, 0) = deptCodeSplit(0)
rng1.Offset(1, 1) = cbo_moduleCode.Value
rng1.Offset(1, 2) = cbo_moduleName.Value
rng1.Offset(1, 3) = txt_studentNo.Value
rng1.Offset(1, 4) = cbo_day.Value
rng1.Offset(1, 5) = cbo_period.Value
' rng1.Offset(1, 6) = weeks
rng1.Offset(1, 7) = cbo_weeks.Value
rng1.Offset(1, 8) = cbo_semester.Value
rng1.Offset(1, 9) = cbo_rounds.Value
rng1.Offset(1, 10) = cbo_priority.Value
' rng1.Offset(1, 11) = lectureStyle
rng1.Offset(1, 12) = txt_noRooms.Value
rng1.Offset(1, 13) = cbo_park.Value
' rng1.Offset(1, 14) = fac
' rng1.Offset(1, 15) = pref
rng1.Offset(1, 16) = txt_specialReq.Value

End Sub
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clarification on what exactly you are having trouble with would help me give you a better answer.  What it sounds like is that you are trying to fill a range that is unknown in size as a user can choose up to 15 items in the first set, 1 in the second set and up to three in the third set.  So, the first thing I would make some arrays to hold the items chosen by the user in a way like..

```
      Dim group1 as arraylist
      Dim group2 as arraylist
      Dim group3 as arraylist

      ' Go through checkboxes and add values if they are checked
      if checkbox1.checked = true then
       group1.add(1)
      end if ' do that for each checkbox or if you have a checklistbox do 

      for each thing in checklistbox1
        if thing.checked=true then
        group1.add(checklistbox1.indexof(thing)-1)
        end if
        next
```

Do the same type of procedure for group 2 and group 3

```
        if not dropdown1.selecteditem = "no preference" then
          group3.add(...)
         end if ' so an and so forth
```

Now, you can add group1, group2 and group3 to the sheet like

```
         Dim StartingRange as range = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)
         Dim total_items as integer = (group1.items.count + group2.items.count + group3.items.count)
```

I don't know which way you want to add items, in the row or in the columns but you can size the startingrange by...

```
           startrange.resize(totalitems, 1) ' resizes range to 1 column and total items in rows
```

then

```
           Dim cell as variant

          for each cell in startrange
            cell.value = group1.item(0)
            group1.removeat(0)   ' this effectively moves the item at index 1, to index 0
             next
```

do for rest of groups

if that doesn't help let me know.  My VBA is a little bit rusty, so I may have missed a few things in the code like 'Set' ranges, etc, so I do apologize for that.

Comment: I want to add items in the row

Comment: Then instead of resize(totalitems, 1), do resize (1, totalitems)

Comment: `' rng1.Offset(1, 6) = weeks` is the code segment which refers to the cell in which all the weeks have to go. How do I insert them into that cell?

Comment: I'm kind of confused to what you are actually placing in the cell, but I would try rng1.Offset(1,6).value = "whatever you want" or if you are saying you want the value that is in rng1.offset(1,6) to be inserted into another cell, then rng1.range("thecellyouwant").value = rng1.offset(1,6).value, let me know if I am not understanding the question correctly.